# Sending php cron script results/output to an e-mail

Tags: php, cron

I am running a cron job every night (importing products from feed to my e-shop - Prestashop) and I would like to get the results to my e-mail after the script ends.
Can you help me to implement this?

I have cron.php in which is this:

```
<?php

include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/importfast.php');

$importFast = new ImportFast();
$importFast->cron();

?>
```

Can  this be done? Maybee to this file or to /importfast.php? And how to make it?

Thank you very much for help,

Daniel

Comment: If you output anything from a CRON job, it will get sent via email. Just look up how to use CRON

Comment: What RiggsFolly wrote, iit's a feature of cron.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)